# comment font legibility on ELL (letter-spacing)

Tags: feature-request

Would it be possible to tweak the letter-spacing CSS of the font used for comments, to add just a bit more daylight between letters? I didn't know what Irn Bru was and read it as Im Bru. On my Chromebook 'rn' looks like 'm' in comments.

Comment: It seems unlikely that SE would change the font. Can you try to yourself, following [these steps](https://mcmw.abilitynet.org.uk/how-to-change-the-font-in-the-chrome-web-browser-in-chrome-os)? Otherwise you may need a userscript (I assume this is your personal device and not something with restrictions like a school or work device).

Comment: This wouldn't be a change of font, BTW, just a slight  change to the `letter-spacing` setting. I have tried to make changes on the device in settings (font family and size) but the website settings are taking precedence (as that page warns).  And font *size* tweaks don't fix it. When I use pinch to magnify the page,  the letters rn continue to look like an m until the font reaches a gargantuan size, where a single comment textarea occupies most of the width of my screen.

Comment: The poor kerning on the default font has been causing issues for years... [I'm pretty sure the question says 'pom' rather than 'porn'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/58773/9161)

Comment: @ColleenV: That was actually me, in a former life, on a different machine with a different browser, and a different email address that I no longer have :-) It's much simpler than **kerning**, btw, which relates to specific letter-pairs. All that would need to be done is to set the CSS `letter-spacing` to offer a little more daylight between letters.

Comment: I ' d  l i k e  a  m o r e  l e g i b l e  f o n t  n o t  s p a c i n g , b u t  a  C S S  c h a n g e  i s  m o r e  l i k e l y  I  g u e s s . :) I'm glad to see you're still around. Ugh my double spaces between words were removed.

Comment: @ColleenV  Luckily, the letter-spacing CSS directive allows for spaces that are a fractional width of a space (e.g. 0.01em). Here's an interactive demo: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing